# osx macOS public key import to keychain duplicate

Tags: swift, macos, keychain, macos-sierra

I am trying to permanently import an RSA public key into the keychain

```
let params: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag as AnyObject,
    kSecValueData: data as AnyObject,
    kSecReturnPersistentRef: true as AnyObject
]

let persistKey = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>(mutating: nil)
let status = SecItemAdd(params as CFDictionary, persistKey)
```

....

Unfortunately the key (regardless which) gets errSecDuplicateItem but if I select it with SecItemCopyMatching.... i get errSecItemNotFound

I tried multiple solutions like adding different attributes like account etc.. but most of this eventually resulted in unknown parameter errors.

I'm sure the key is correct cause SecKeyCreateWithData is fine with it.

**edit:**
Thats the way to collect the key:

```
        let params: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
            kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag as AnyObject,
            kSecReturnRef: true as AnyObject
        ]

    var keyRef: AnyObject? = nil
    status = SecItemCopyMatching(params, &keyRef)
```

The key is also not findable if you look it up manually in the keychain app

Comment: Please share the code you use to look up the item.

Comment: @DaveWeston I edited the original question

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem. On iOS the code works, but not on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The code worked fine for me on iOS but I could not get it to work for macOS either.
I then rewrote the code by using Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_as_data

So the code to get a `SecKeyRef` from a public key given as `Data` is just:

```
let options: [String: Any] = [kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                              kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                              kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String : 2048]
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData,
                                     options as CFDictionary,
                                     &error) else {
                                        throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
}
```